# list.remove(element) weird behaviour in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The following snippet gives an output which I can't understand:

```
list1 = [4, 4, 4, 4]
for e in list1:
    list1.remove(e)

print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[4, 4]
```

Please help me understand why I am getting this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There problem here is, you alter the list while iterating through the list.
To understand that, try:

```
list1 = [4, 4, 4, 4]
for e in list1:
    list1.remove(e)
    print(list1)

print(list1)
```

The output indicates that after the second iteration, the iteration gets over, since the length of the list reduced to 2 and the 3rd iteration checks for a 3rd element.
Output:

```
#after 1st iteration
[4, 4, 4]
#after second
[4, 4]
```

---

Now to achieve what you are trying to (remove all elements):

```
list1 = [4, 4, 4, 4]
# Either:
list1.clear() # removes all the elements
# Or:
for i in range(len(list1)): #pops out the last element for 4 times (so here, the change in list doesn't matter)
    list1.pop()
#Or:
for i in range(len(list1)-1,-1,-1):
    list1.remove(list1[i])
```

---

**The exact solution in your way**:

```
for i in list(list1):
    list1.remove(i)
```

This creates a new list from the list1 and isin't affected when you loop through the list1. This is beacuse we iterate through the new list.

Answer (score 1):

As InfinityTM says, you are altering the list as you are iterring through it.

### Here is a hint to what is going on:

Say you have a `list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` *(I changed the value to make it clearer)*.

On first run of the for loop, index = 0. Take the element of the list at *index 0* and remove it. This means remove **a** from the list. But here is the catch, now `list == ['b', 'c', 'd']`.

Second iteration, index = 1. Take the element of the list at *index 1* and remove it. This corresponds to **c**. Remember list was `['b', 'c', 'd']` after first iteration. So now that we remove **c**, the list becomes `['b', 'd']`.

Next iteration, index = 2. Take the element of the list at *index 2* and remove 
it. The index is too high for the list which only have 2 elements (`['b', 'd']`). End of the loop!

list ends up being `['b', 'd']`.

```
_list = list('abcd')

for i, e in enumerate(_list): 
    print(f'index: {i}\telement: {e}')
    print(f'list before removal: {_list}') 

    _list.remove(e) 
    print(f'list after removal: {_list}\n') 

print(_list) 

# index: 0  element: a
# list before removal: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
# list after removal: ['b', 'c', 'd']
#
# index: 1  element: c
# list before removal: ['b', 'c', 'd']
# list after removal: ['b', 'd']
#
# ['b', 'd']
```

### How to do it

They are many ways. One solution would be to set the list to *empty list*: `list1 = []`

If you understood the problem, you might have foreseen a bigger issue. In the previous solution, we now what the end result should be. So we just set the list to whatever we need. But what if we don't ? For instance if you were to sort a list ?. Then another solution is to rebuild a new list while iterating over the orignal one.

```
# as an exemple let's say you only want to keep odd numbers from a list

_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

tmp_list = []
for e in _list:
    if e % 2 != 0:
        tmp_list.append(e)
_list = tmp_list 

print(_list) # [1, 3, 5]
```